# Generate a typescript interface that references itself

Tags: typescript, recursion, interface, self-reference, mapped-types

EDIT: I have rewritten this question to be much clearer.

I am trying to programmatically infer an interface which references itself.

I am writing some code which can encode a recursive structure in binary. For example:

```
const myTreeEncoder = Struct(Self => ({
    name: Str,
    children: List(Self)
});
```

This can encode structures like this from binary and back:

```
myTreeEncoder.encode(someUint8Array, {
    name: 'parent',
    children: [{
        name: 'child',
        children: []
    }]
});
```

The problem is, how can the encode function be typed correctly so it expects an input of:

```
interface BinaryTree {
    name: string;
    children: BinaryTree[];
}
```

Here is a minimal reproducible [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIgQewCZwEYA2EAPACoB8yA3gFDL3IQY4QAUAzmFBHALYBcyAKqgwADgCCUKHACeAGmQA3OAQCuEQaQCUgpZmDY6DbBCymOXHgOGjJ0ubuSkA3DQC+NGlhCdkAZS5+dHN8ImJOKFAAc0oAXmpjeiZzNkjrQRFwexkFZVUNQUiY7USGcuQAekrkADp65HZMXhRU5DBMZAB3KMh2gAsUYpBo5FFOsEHGqz4k5Hd5OdNUy24+TLspXNLaCoZquoamluQ2juQ17AGhrhjkTDUwe5hr6bXeOfLuMDUoEGQAOQQAAefAADkQAXNPJ4aDA1BgwMBMP8ADLAThkcisMCyMGaNDMXCEEgUJwhHBhUkAbQAupRdgxvr9-oy9ikWKsMrZsls5IoVOoCaQ6TtPnsqjV6rVGs1Wix2p0esA+pMUHAHLIxuAJlN0rMJfNFoblpz9TYsuI+bIxYbygdpbKTmdOpdXhrcvdHs9XubxXtmX9kHS3IbPOUYV5cfjCaESQARYAIJEojWyMiMYGQEDYdj3PAAKzMYHiiQAkNSANLa5AAawgskwL1ItMEFOJ4RFlfpbncbho0ZQAElwBAYNB4EgAPIwLHIBKkTPZ3Oxykk4igcdQYSUAD8wmQghAECU0H78MRyP+gSgamTGZBy7zmELxex0SY0DgHSggg4EAIGA2yJKksVKOJKHbKlE2TK80zA4C407Bk5gOEdkDgC4eAIMZeAhCAWnAb8rzrBt22gPMNRQNR2AgK5QHYQwUA5UxUJqOAc2QU1TEVLC4GwSplVVKYXyLZN8iFPNxl9GYPnKIgnnrWRyKgdhQwYHw-G4dg1AIJ4EjZCoWLSWSNl5TUBQKYVbTtegHSOOVTgVc4hJQNV8zEp5pPcv0w2NCVuJM94zKtTUbNs+yZWOeUePON13NE4svSeJsZPef0KkDVl3AwvNXAy8MGEK+glJUvMEg-Y8ZB-VhtN0sBtHU+gsqwnS9N7LxNKeXhZFIbgIBU+cAi4O8wFYfwAJeCDkFYQyQD4Akb38+gEH6YACGwbgQEEdFOHGybtA8bRGq8SoACpnCneMp0EAAJTAul4j8nj6iAIBHSBYEQNzOjwTQ6Auqh5paIpbhGRRVvWzamC0fqPonb66XDM7KgHPEUFe97Ry+pAhvhrdJwgGdiEHVKesxlTyBcIA)

Comment: There is no problem with the self-referencing interface `BinaryTree` as you have written it.  Can you not just write `const myTreeEncoder: Encodable<BinaryTree> = ...` or `const myTreeEncoder = Struct<BinaryTree>(...)`?  Where I am getting lost is with the example `const someUint8Array = myTreeEncoder.encode(...)` since the `encode` function in the `Encodable` interface takes two arguments and returns nothing.  But here you are passing it one argument and expecting it to return something.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks for pointing out the encode issue, this was a typo and I've now corrected it to match the example.

The aim is to infer the resulting BinaryTree interface from the definition in the first code snippet rather than having to write it separately as an interface (so effectively twice)

Comment: In general, detecting recursion is a really tough ask because it's hard (impossible?) for TS to see an object that is n levels deep and know that its type is infinitely recursive rather than exactly n levels deep.  You would need to know that you are looking for something recursive and then see what specific form it takes using `extends` and `infer`. At which point you're not saving much code vs just applying the know `BinaryTree` interface. It would be something like `type IsRecursive<T> = T extends {children: T[] | []} ? Omit<T, 'children'> & {children: T[]} : never;`

Comment: That said, right now you're not get any information about your `Struct` mapping other than that it is an `object`, so you can certainly refine better than that.  I'm still working on it -- this is an interesting one!