# Typescript array.map doesn't distribute intersection types properly

Tags: typescript, intersection, array-map, mapped-types

I have an array of type `object[] & Tree[]` but `arr.map(child => ...)` infers the type of the child as `object` rather than `object & Tree`.

Is there any way to avoid this without extra casting?

Notably `Tree` extends `object` but typescript doesn't seem to realise this and merge the two parts of the intersection type.

EDIT - Minimal reproducible example:

This is contrived, but based off my other recent question [Transform a typescript object type to a mapped type that references itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305599/transform-a-typescript-object-type-to-a-mapped-type-that-references-itself)

```
interface BasicInterface {
    name: string;
    children: object[];
}

function getBasic<T extends object>(input: T): BasicInterface {
    return input as BasicInterface;
}

export const basicTree = getBasic({
    name: 'parent',
    children: [{
        name: 'child',
        children: []
    }]
});
```

The point is the code below has access to "basicTree" and its inferred type. For this example I have defined
BasicInterface, but in practice this is generated automatically and I haven't found a way to programatically
generate a recursive interface.

I would like to add the recursive type of children back as the original interface defines.

Rather than completely redefine BasicInterface in the code as this could be a lot of boilerplate, I am trying
to "enhance" the definition of the basicTree's type with the correct recursive definition.

But this falls down when getting the children's type. Perhaps there is a simpler solution?

```
type RestoredInterface = typeof basicTree & {
    children: RestoredInterface[]
};

function getTree(basic: BasicInterface): RestoredInterface {
    return basic as RestoredInterface;
}

const restoredTree = getTree(basicTree);

const names = restoredTree.children.map(child => child.name);
```

Comment: intersections of functions are interpreted as [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), so the call to `arr.map()` is likely considered calling the first overload; i.e., the `object[]`'s `map` method.  I'm wondering why the type isn't `(object & Tree)[]` or `Tree[]`?  Where's the intersection happening?  Could you provide a [mcve] so someone can advise you?

Comment: Ah I see thankyou. I will update the original question with an example for clarity

Comment: The inferred type of `basicTree` is just `BasicInterface`, and your intersection doesn't result in anything like `object[] & Tree[]`; instead it's just `object[] & OtherThingsThatAreNotArrays`.  Are you sure this example reproduces your issue?

Comment: `interface RestoredInterface extends BasicInterface { children: RestoredInterface[] }` might do what you want?  Note that I think there's a typo in your example above since you have `RestoredInterface` in a place I expect to see `RestoredInterface[]`.

Comment: Updated to include your correction thanks. The example is meant to demonstrate that I'm struggling to see how to combine two object interfaces `A` and `B` so that a child array called 'children' has type `(ElementOf<A['children']> & ElementOf<B['children']>)[]` rather than `ElementOf<A['children']>[] & ElementOf<B['children']>`. Maybe I need to use some recursive merge operation rather than a intersection

Comment: In the above, have you tried changing your definition of `RestoredInterface` to `interface RestoredInterface extends BasicInterface { children: RestoredInterface[] }`?  That should fix the problem.  If that doesn't meet your needs, please edit the example code to reflect this.

Comment: The example is contrived - in practice, BasicInterface is programatically generated and the code below only gets basicTree as an object - so the question is how can you "extend" an interface without having reference to its definition

Comment: @jcalz see my answer. let me know the correct way to credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a weird solution. Just change the order in the declaration. That's weird, but it works:

```
type RestoredInterface = {
    children: RestoredInterface[]
} & typeof basicTree;
```

Edit: Here is an [explanation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11961#issuecomment-257444466).

A better solution can be something like this:

```
type RestoredInterface = Omit<typeof basicTree, 'children'> & {
    children: RestoredInterface[]
};
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictFunctionTypes=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM7AQSXNeJZAbwFgAoZK5EOAWwgC5kMwpQBzAbguuQQAWwADYATKBBDMA9gCMAVhARgA2gF0e5AL4UKMAK4hlwaSGQcIYdFgQAeACrIIAD0ghRGZHMXKAfAApQAAd9MGZ7AEpma2w8SFhEFDJKagkwfSgzYNDkTDRMWPwEpE0dcgoXIOkoMH5TVmRZAoR7CRQAXnNLGIR-ZL5aBmYAciC4CXBhgBpeakERcUlmFX6%20akGmZGH5sWnZtf4hMQnltX3kLTPtCM0KMABPIJQAJQhWaohROIJE5E6Hp7SGCNZqtCAoABkJHOO0WUmQr3eEi%20RUIEHUFC0t3IAJebzAHxR8TRAEY-sgAPJ0YBgWy4oEgmxgiBTLawibDXzIKGrKjspYI-GE77FdFXLG6HGPPFIz4itEAJnJvMOCxOgtlRJ%20SAx2m5yHpwKaTLa2IMRjAJjMFjAzP8xuw0Wa8sSUQ1BORLqIKrSGTMDoQuU8iI9ctRiVKkoQ9VqEk1zPJNrtAeZNwowksNHob3JcdDomZADp%20SBC3Q4EF-LC-lzYYWNmnyuRoyAGnnCcyyZ0k217aC2hEg%207heGkCTNBtPJ128jO8WjnCyxWqwua6qxPXs42KC220LZ20ld3LMn%20%20DB3kQyPiYkFRPs1PkDPPsyFfO1ZIl5Xq%201awvNwwjZAA)

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I've also proposed a solution, but this is the only appropriate solution when `typeof basicTree` is more complex e.g. if it is a union type itself, it doesn't have statically known keys and extends can't be used

Answer (score 0):

Based off an observation from jcalz, it is actually possible to simply extend the original interface. I was confused because it is programatically defined, but that's not a problem if you name it first:

```
type BasicTreeInterface = typeof basicTree;

interface RestoredInterface extends BasicTreeInterface {
    children: RestoredInterface[]
};

const restoredTree = getTree(basicTree);

const names = restoredTree.children.map(child => {
    // Child is of type RestoredInterface
});
```